# Azure Function does not resolve variable

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I ve been trying to get an OAuth 2.0 token from Google Analytics via a function app in Azure.

I am following this tutorial:

https://richardswinbank.net/adf/access_google_analytics_with_azure_data_factory#get_an_oauth_token_in_adf

There is a part were an URL is extracted from a variable:

```
var kvClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_URL")), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
            string keyJson = kvClient.GetSecret("KEY_VAULT_URL").Value.Value;
```

In Azure portal, under my function app -> Settings -> Configuration -> Application settings is the definition for KEY_VAULT_URL.

But the variable does not seem to resolve, because I get this error:

```
2021-10-14T14:02:24.371 [Error] Executed 'GetOAuthToken' (Failed, Id=bad02220-c792-4c53-af41-621c6a9d12345, Duration=32ms)The request URI contains an invalid name: KEY_VAULT_URLStatus: 400 (Bad Request)ErrorCode: BadParameterContent:{"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"The request URI contains an invalid name: KEY_VAULT_URL"}}Headers:Cache-Control: no-cachePragma: no-cachex-ms-keyvault-region: germanywestcentralx-ms-client-request-id: 0344c4b6-98d9-4ade-9c7f-cb058abd123x-ms-request-id: d35bd092-faf4-4567-99e4-4aba0123d7bx-ms-keyvault-service-version: 1.9.132.3x-ms-keyvault-network-info: conn_type=Ipv4;addr=51.216.128.119;act_addr_fam=InterNetwork;X-Powered-By: REDACTEDStrict-Transport-Security: REDACTEDX-Content-Type-Options: REDACTEDDate: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 14:02:23 GMTContent-Length: 101Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8Expires: -1
```

The value of the variable looks like this:

```
https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/
```

Maybe there is a mistake? I removed the trailing slash, but the output is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong in the tutorial. It should not be a variable. It has to be the name of the secret.

```
kvClient.GetSecret("KEY_VAULT_URL")
```